# How are these three functions working together?

Tags: php

I am following a  php book and am not understanding a few functions.

Specifically,public function DisplayMenu($buttons). I know this creates a table for the menu (home, contact etc and spaces them out). And the parameters here

```
 public function DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, $active = true)

$width = 100/count($buttons);
    Here is what I am not understanding. Im setting a variable called width to be 100/count ? lets say buttons are 4 so 100/4 25? What is the point of the 25? Also,

$this -> DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, !$this->IsURLCurrentPage($url));
```

I know what they produce on screen but not understadning the key parts of these fucntiosn. Can some one shed a tiny bit of light.

// variables declared

```
public $content;
  public $title = 'TLA Consulting Pty Ltd';
  public $keywords = 'TLA Consulting, Three Letter Abbreviation, 
                   some of my best friends are search engines';
  public $buttons = array( 'Home'     => 'home.php', 
                        'Contact'  => 'contact.php', 
                        'Services' => 'services.php', 
                        'Site Map' => 'map.php'
                      );

  // class Page's operations
  public function __set($name, $value)
  {
    $this->$name = $value;
  }

public function DisplayMenu($buttons)
  {

    echo "<table width='100%' bgcolor='red' cellpadding='3' 
                cellspacing='4'\n";
    echo "  <tr>\n";

    $width = 100/count($buttons);

    while (list($name, $url) = each($buttons))
    {

      $this -> DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, !$this->IsURLCurrentPage($url));
    }
    echo "  </tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
  }


  {
    if ($active)
    {
      echo "<td width ='$width%'>
            <a href ='$url'>
            <img src ='s-logo' alt ='$name' border ='0' /></a>
            <a href ='$url'><span class='menu'>$name</span></a></td>";
    }  
    else
    {
      echo "<td width ='$width%'>
            <img src ='side-logo.gif'>
            <span class='test'>$name</span></td>";
    }  
  }





   public function IsURLCurrentPage($url)
  //#determines weather a url for the button points to the current page.
  // #the server[php_self,$url] returns a number if the string in $url is inside the superglobal variable $_server[pph]
  {
    if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $url )==false)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }






public function DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, $active = true)
  //outputs a single menu button if button is to point to the page to are on, you display an inactive button
#I think width just gives the table cell a % value.  $name involves a setter function declared up top? ,
  {
    if ($active)
    {
      echo "<td width ='$width%'>
            <a href ='$url'>
            <img src ='s-logo' alt ='$name' border ='0' /></a>
            <a href ='$url'><span class='menu'>$name</span></a></td>";
    }  
    else
    {
      echo "<td width ='$width%'>
            <img src ='side-logo.gif'>
            <span class='test'>$name</span></td>";
    }  
  }
```

Comment: It sets a table cell width in % depending on the number of buttons. So if you have 4 buttons each cell in a row will be 25% wide.

Comment: Ohh dude thank you alot/ Any idea on what $this -> DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, !$this->IsURLCurrentPage($url)); actually does?

Comment: It creates a table cell that is `$width`% wide and a 'button' with an image in it. The image will display `$name` text if an image is not found and `$name` will also show as text in 'button'. A 'button' with have a link to `$url` and `!$this->IsURLCurrentPage($url)` means that a button which has a link to current page will not have a link or simply it means the button which has a link to current page will be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is missing the `class` declaration, but we move on...

Below, is where your class attributes are declared.

```
public $content;
public $title = 'TLA Consulting Pty Ltd';
public $keywords = 'TLA Consulting, Three Letter Abbreviation, 
               some of my best friends are search engines';
public $buttons = array( 'Home'     => 'home.php', 
                    'Contact'  => 'contact.php', 
                    'Services' => 'services.php', 
                    'Site Map' => 'map.php'
                  );
```

`__set()` is a magic method from PHP. You can check all of them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) later. We'll focus on `__set()`. It means that every time you set an attribute in your object it will define and set this attribute, even if you haven't declared it on your class.

```
// class Page's operations
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->$name = $value;
}
```

Next, we have `DisplayMenu`, which renders the menu on screen. The `$width`, means the width of each button. So, if you have 4 buttons in `$buttons`, it will split up the space, which in this case is 100%, among them, thus, resulting in 25% for each button.

```
public function DisplayMenu($buttons)
{

    echo "<table width='100%' bgcolor='red' cellpadding='3' 
            cellspacing='4'\n";
    echo "  <tr>\n";

    $width = 100/count($buttons);

    while (list($name, $url) = each($buttons))
    {
        // This will render the button on screen.
        // Params:
        // 1 The width of the button.
        // 2 The name of the button.
        // 3 The url the button points to.
        // 4 Checks if the button url is the same url of the current page. 
        $this->DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, !$this->IsURLCurrentPage($url));
     }
     echo "  </tr>\n";
     echo "</table>\n";
}
```

`IsURLCurrentPage` method checks if the `$url` passed as argument is the current URL and returns true or false. True if it is the current page, false if not.

```
public function IsURLCurrentPage($url)
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $url )==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally, `DisplayButton` will render the actual button. Each one of them is rendered individually.

```
public function DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, $active = true)
{
    // This will, in practice verify for you if 
    // the current page is the same of the button the user clicked. 
    // If it is, it will display the button without the link for that 
    // button, or with a disabled link. 
    // You'll notice it will show differently. Maybe 
    // also with some different color or style according to the CSS class.
    // Remember that $active is the result of the IsURLCurrentPage().

    if ($active)
    {
        echo "<td width ='$width%'>
              <a href ='$url'>
              <img src ='s-logo' alt ='$name' border ='0' /></a>
              <a href ='$url'><span class='menu'>$name</span></a></td>";
    }  
    else
    {
        echo "<td width ='$width%'>
              <img src ='side-logo.gif'>
              <span class='test'>$name</span></td>";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you i love you, also for iscurrent, is that also what allows me to display my page? Like if I create a new file called contact.php, is this what allows contact to be clickable and go to the new page?

Comment: `isURLCurrentPage` will check if the current page the user is in is the same page of the button being rendered. If it's true, it will make the button disabled. If it's not the same page, it will make the button clickable, enabling you to go to another page. So if you click in "contact" you will be redirected to that page, and your link will be disabled. If in the "contact" page you click "services", in the services page the "contact"  button will be enabled again.

Comment: Thank you, also where exactly is the setter method being used at ? In the code,     while (list($name, $url) = each($buttons))
Is this somehow using the set method and spitting out the actual home, contact, etc page? Could you give me an example where set is being used?

Comment: Your class has it defined, but in this case it's not being used. Check an example of the use of `__set()` here: https://eval.in/593419 see if that clears up.